# Passing data within an app between devices in same network

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

I am currently developing a Universal Windows 10 application that is planned to run both on the PC + Mobile and the Raspberry Pi 2.

I was wondering what would be the best way for these two apps to pass data from one another through a local network and not using Azure. It is required that for every transaction done on each device, it gets transmitted over to another.

We also need to remote control the Raspberry Pi 2, like manage the data and shut it down using the app.

We are planning to build a RESTful API that will run on the same local network to facilitate this but I'm not pretty sure what APIs to use for this.

What are the necessary APIs that will be good for this requirement?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of what you transfer, I found this:

- BackgroundUploader class
- Windows.Web.Http namespace.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207140?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2